# toprettyxml() : write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, xml, utf-8

My program saves a bit of XML data to a file in a prettyfied format from an XML string. This does the trick:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
dom = parseString(strXML)
with open(file_name + ".xml", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    outfile.write(dom.toprettyxml())
```

However, I noticed that my XML header is missing an encoding parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Since my data is susceptible of containing many Unicode characters, I must make sure UTF-8 is also specified in the XML encoding field.

Now, looking at the minidom documentation, I read that "an additional keyword argument encoding can be used to specify the encoding field of the XML header". So I try this:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
dom = parseString(strXML)
with open(file_name + ".xml", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    outfile.write(dom.toprettyxml(encoding="UTF-8"))
```

But then I get:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Why doesn't the first piece of code yield that error? And what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

R.

Comment: change "w" to "wb": done

Comment: OK, but then will be output file really be encoded in UTF-8? And most importantly, why? Why does adding the encoding argument in the toprettyxml method require me to open the file as binary when I don't need to otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toxml) emphasis mine:

> **With no argument**, the XML header does not specify an encoding, and the result is **Unicode string** if the default encoding cannot represent all characters in the document. Encoding this string in an encoding other than UTF-8 is likely incorrect, since UTF-8 is the default encoding of XML.
>
> **With an explicit encoding argument**, the result is a **byte string** in the specified encoding. It is recommended that this argument is always specified. To avoid UnicodeError exceptions in case of unrepresentable text data, the encoding argument should be specified as “utf-8”.

So the `write` method outputs a different object type whether encoding is set or not (which is rather confusing if you ask me)

So you can fix by removing the encoding:

```
with open(file_name + ".xml", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    outfile.write(dom.toprettyxml())
```

or open your file in *binary mode* which then accepts byte strings to be written to

```
with open(file_name + ".xml", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(dom.toprettyxml(encoding="utf8"))
```

Comment: Ah that clarifies it (although I agree it's quite confusing). I hadn't seen that bit of explanation in the document I consulted. Many thanks!!! :-)

Comment: This does not take line-ending into consideration. On Windows, line-ending is usually CRLF rather than LF only. Writing in `Binary` mode will not automatically convert line-endings, but `Text` mode will do.

Comment: okay, it is well known but line termination doesn't matter with xml files.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem as follow:

```
with open(targetName, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(dom.toprettyxml(indent='\t', encoding='utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `wb` mode for output, because it does not take line-ending conversion into consideration (which, for example, converts `\n` to `\r\n` on Windows when using `Text` mode). I instead use the following method to do this:

```
dom = minidom.parseString(utf_8_xml_text)

out_byte = dom.toprettyxml(encoding="utf-8")
out_text = out_byte.decode("utf-8")

with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(out_text)
```

For python version higher than 3.9, using built-in `indent` function instead.